# Counting on groupAgent in Sequelize.js results in 'missing FROM-clause entry for table TicketGroupAgent' error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to count on groupAgent but it gives me error missing FROM-clause entry for table "TicketGroupAgent
this is what i am tried and using this query using findandCountAll.Please help me i stuck on this from 2 days

```
 {
  const query = { where: {} };
  query.include = [
    {
      model: TicketGroupAgent,
      as: 'groupAgents',
      attributes: [
        'id',
        [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('TicketGroupAgent.id')), 'agentsCount'],
      ],
      include: [
        {
          model: User,
          as: 'agentDetails',
          attributes: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'fullName', 'avatar'],
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
  return query;
};
```

Comment: The error is likely due to a missing association between your main model and the TicketGroupAgent model. Would need to see the models to help much further.

Comment: this.hasMany(TicketGroupAgent, {
        foreignKey: 'ticketGroupId',
        as: 'groupAgents',
      });
  this.belongsTo(TicketGroup, {
        foreignKey: 'ticketGroupId',
        as: 'group',
      });

Comment: Check that the table name and model name for the "TicketGroupAgent" model are consistent. The table name should be the same as the model name defined in your Sequelize model.

Comment: & Ensure that the foreign key references are accurate in the associations. The foreign key used in the hasMany association (TicketGroupAgent) should match the foreign key used in the belongsTo association (TicketGroup).